# SWT Combo disable item

Tags: java, combobox, swt

I'm looking for solution for a little task.
I am using SWT.
I have a Combo class:

```
public class ComboBoxComponent<T> extends Combo {
    private ComboViewer comboListViewer;

    public ComboBoxComponent(Composite composite, int i) {
        super(composite, i);
        comboListViewer = new ComboViewer(this);
        setVisibleItemCount(15);
        comboListViewer.setContentProvider(new org.eclipse.jface.viewers.ArrayContentProvider());
        comboListViewer.setLabelProvider(new LabelProvider());
    }

    public void setDataModelList(T defaultObject, Collection<T> obj) {
        Collection<T> defaultCollection = new LinkedHashSet<T>();
        if (defaultObject != null)
            defaultCollection.add(defaultObject);
        defaultCollection.addAll(obj);
        comboListViewer.setInput(defaultCollection);
        select(0);
        notifySelection();
    }

    public void notifySelection() {
        Event event = new Event();
        event.type = SWT.Selection;
        event.widget = this;
        event.display = getDisplay();
        event.time = (int) new Date().getTime();
        this.notifyListeners(SWT.Selection, event);
    }

    @Override
    protected void checkSubclass() {

    }
}
```

I want to disable for selecting some items in combo, how could I do it?

Comment: Disable the items according which criteria?

Comment: @JuanManuel like someClass.getId() == -1L, something else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With SWT, disable items it is not possible for a ComboBox, you can remove them. You could use JComboBox from Swing to disable items.

You can bridge Swing components creating a SWT_AWT frame and a AWT panel like this

```
java.awt.Frame frame = SWT_AWT.new_Frame();
java.awt.Panel panel = new java.awt.Panel(new java.awt.BorderLayout());
```

and then add the Swing JComboBox to the panel.

```
panel.add(jComboBox);
```

Here's a tutorial for embedding Swing into SWT

http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0280__SWT/EmbededSwingAWTcomponentstoSWT.htm

Comment: is it possible with swt_awt?

Answer (score 0):

Disable items by not putting them into the combo list in the first place. Why should they be there if they are not selectable?

Use a storage class, like for example `ArrayList` to hold your data, then via a loop, input elements into the combo list while excluding the ones that you don't need there.

You can always use `combo.remove(int start, in end);` to remove your items in a specific location after they have already been added to the combo list.

Additionally, you can prevent that item from being used after it's been selected. You can do this by checking it's name or index number and then prevent it from being used somewhere, also prompting the user in general (if that is the logic you are using) is a good idea.